# Python MySql Connector prepared statement and dictionary class

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

How do I make my cursor a prepared statement as well as a dictionary.
I have the following.

```
 cursor(cursor_class = MySQLCursorPrepared)
 prints <class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursorPrepared'>
 cursor(dictionary = True)
 prints <class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursorDict'>
```

So I am overwriting the prepared statement with the dictionary.  I am using the mysql connector for python3.

I have tried

```
 cursor(prepared=True,dictionary=True)
```

That errors with

```
Cursor not available with given criteria: dictionary, prepared
```

Interestingly

```
cursor(cursor_class = MySQLCursorPrepared,dictionary = True)
```

I get no errors but the data not of dictionary type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem. Prepared and Dictionary don't work together.

I reported bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92700

Now we wait ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I found a workaround.  I make it a prepared statement then use dictzip to get the data into a dictionary.

Comment: Seems like they are not going to fix the issue.  I hope they fix the like statement issue as well.  There is currently no clean way of doing a like statement using a prepared statement.  `select * from table where col like %s`

Answer (score 3):

Zipping `cursor.column_names` with the row values is a good workaround:

```
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
query = 'SELECT foo, bar FROM some_table WHERE a = %s AND b = %s'
a = 1
b = 42
cursor.execute(query, [a, b])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    result = dict(zip(cursor.column_names, row))
    print(result['foo'], result['bar'])
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-column-names.html for documentation on `MySQLCursor.column_names`.

Comment: I believe your last line should be print(result['foo'], result['bar'])

Comment: Thanks, @KenIngram. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This naive workaround seems to work for me - if I disable SSL, I can see in 'strace' output that multiple identical queries only get sent to the server once, and I definitely get dictionaries back when I iterate over the cursor's rows:

```
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursorDict, MySQLCursorPrepared

class PreparedDictionaryCursor(MySQLCursorDict, MySQLCursorPrepared):

    pass
```